# insertar titulo de canción en intervalos en una clase title

Tags: php, jquery

espero alguien me pueda ayudar ...

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
 <div class="songtitle"></div>
```

el codigo anterior muestra el titulo de una canción en intervalos de 5 segundos. (esta clase la crea un codigo jquery la cual obtiene el titulo y se la inserta en esa clase cada 5 segundos).

```
<li class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary mr-2" song="" id="track1" title="" artist="">Online</li>
```

en el código anterior en el apartado title="". deseo colocar los datos obtenidos de `<div class="songtitle"></div>` ....

estoy lo tengo resuelto con este codigo en jquery $("#track1").attr('title', (tittle)); en el cual (tittle) inserta el título de la canción en la clase title

El problema está en que lo inserta una sola vez y no se actualiza en intervalos de 5 segundos como los hace el codigo `<div class="songtitle"></div>`.

Necesito eso, porque esta linea :

```
<li class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary mr-2" song="" id="track1" title="" artist="">Online</li>
```

forma parte de un playlist y cuando se está reproduciendo una canción y está termina, comienza otra nueva con un nuevo titulo, y este titulo se debe también actualizar dentro de ese apartado cosa que no sucede, ya que el código se inserta una sola vez y no se actualiza cada 5 segundos como necesito...

La pregunta es: como hacer que se actualice la nueva canción en el apartado title=""?..

P.D.: ya llevo dias partiendome la cabeza y he visto millones de tutoriales y muchas horas de prueba y todas han sido infructuosas... por otro lado este playlist se refleja en una pantalla de un reproductor web que estoy diseñando y que lo muestra la clase title. o sea  `<span  class="title"></span>`. <--- aqui se reflejan los titulos de cada cancion del playlist como si fuera una pantalla...

Si alguien es tan amable y me podrá ayudar? se lo agradecería...

Edito....

Código encargado de buscar el titulo cada 5 segundos

```
<script>

$.SHOUTcast({
   host : '162.210.196.145',
   port : 19950,
   interval : 5000,
   stats : function(data){
     var tittle = (data['songtitle']); 

     $('.songtitle').html(tittle);
    var controlSetTitle=null;
    // En donde corresponda conforme la lógica que manejes
    if (controlSetTitle!=null) clearInterval(controlSetTitle);
    controlSetTitle =setInterval(function(){ 
    $('#track1').attr('title', $('.songtitle').html()); 
    }, 5000);      
 
     //$("#track1").attr('title', (tittle));
     $("#track2").attr('title', 'Música');
     $("#track3").attr('title', 'wake me up');
     $("#track4").attr('title', 'let her cry');   
     $("#track5").attr('title', 'from the inside');
     $("#track6").attr('title', 'Crawling');
     $("#track7").attr('title', 'Numb');
     $("#track8").attr('title', 'In the end');          
   }
}).startStats();


</script>
```

código de player ...

```
var audio;

//Hide Pause Initially
$('#pause').hide();
$('.title').hide();
    
//Initializer - Play First Song
initAudio($('#playlist li:first-child'));
    
function initAudio(element){

    var prueba =  $('.songtitle').html();
    var song = element.attr('song');
    var title = element.attr('title');
    var cover = element.attr('cover');
    var artist = element.attr('artist');

    //Create a New Audio Object
    audio = new Audio('' + song);
    
    if(!audio.currentTime){
        $('#duration').html('00:00');       
    }
        
    $('#audio-player .title').text(' ' + title);    
    $('#audio-player .artist').text(artist);    

    //Insert Cover Image
    
    $('img.cover').attr('src','img/covers/' + cover);
    
    $('#playlist li').removeClass('active');
    element.addClass('active');
  
    $(audio).on('ended', function(){
    $('#next').trigger('click');

  });    
}


//Play Button
$('#play').click(function(){
    audio.play();
    $('#play').hide();
    $('#pause').show();
    $('.title').show();
    $('#duration').fadeIn(400);
    
    showDuration();
});

//Pause Button
$('#pause').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    $('#pause').hide();
    $('#play').show();
    $('.title').show();
    $('.artist').show();
});
    
//Stop Button
$('#stop').click(function(){
    audio.pause();      
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    $('#pause').hide();
    $('#play').show();
    $('#duration').fadeOut(400);
    $('.title').hide();
    $('.artist').hide();
});

//Prev Button
$('#prev').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    var prev = $('#playlist li.active').prev();
    if (prev.length == 0) {
        prev = $('#playlist li:last-child');
    }
    initAudio(prev);
    audio.play();
    showDuration();
});

//Next Button
$('#next').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    var next = $('#playlist li.active').next();
    if (next.length == 0) {
        next = $('#playlist li:first-child');
    }
    initAudio(next);
    audio.play();
    showDuration();
});

//Playlist Song Click
$('#playlist li').click(function () {
    audio.pause();
    initAudio($(this));
    $('#play').hide();
    $('#pause').show();
    $('#duration').fadeIn(400);
    $('.title').show();
    $('.artist').show();
    audio.play();
    showDuration();
});

//Volume Control
$('#volume').change(function(){
    audio.volume = parseFloat(this.value / 10);
});
    
//Time Duration
function showDuration(){
    $(audio).bind('timeupdate', function(){
        //Get hours and minutes
        var s = parseInt(audio.currentTime % 60);
        var m = parseInt((audio.currentTime / 60) % 60);
        //Add 0 if seconds less than 10
        if (s < 10) {
            s = '0' + s;
        }
        if (m < 10) {
            m = '0' + m;    
        }
        $('#duration').html(m + ':' + s);   
        var value = 0;
        if (audio.currentTime > 0) {
            value = Math.floor((100 / audio.duration) * audio.currentTime);
        }
        $('#progress').css('width',value+'%');
    });
}
```

Sosprecho que en el siguinte codigo está el problema de actualización de los titulos...

```
 $('#audio-player .title').text(' ' + title);
```

Creo que este codigo es el que no actualiza los titulos

Cualquier ayuda será super apreciada... gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Ya que falta el código que se encarga de ello (el que se debe estar repitiendo cada 5 segundos). Te sugiero lo siguiente:

```
// Declara variable global a la página
var controlSetTitle=null;



// En donde corresponda conforme la lógica que manejes
if (controlSetTitle!=null) clearInterval(controlSetTitle);
controlSetTitle =setInterval(function(){ 
$('#track1').attr('title', $('.songtitle').html()); 
}, 5000);
```

la parte del `if` asi como la asignación debes colocarla luego que obtienes los datos de la canción; desde luego; implica que tengas un evento/momento que *se entera* tu código que cambio la canción.

Comment: tu codigo funciona, lo puedes ver agregado en el codigo del playlist, creo que el problema es mas del lado de los titulos en el  reproductor que del lado de los titulos... gracias por tu aporte...